# TFS Linking Backlog items

Tags: tfs

In TFS whats the easiest way of linking a backlog item to a large number of other backlog items, without doing them one at a time?

I do not have access to the underlying database so am unable to write a query to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd stay away from the SQL Query. Instead, I'd either use the API or Web Services. Here's an example API call to retrieve and edit a work item:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130323.aspx

You could modify that to add the links. Would be much safer, easier, and much more supported than going directly to the database.

Answer (score 1):

I put together a GUI tool that helps do this.

It is called WI Assistant.

It can be found here: http://wiassistant.codeplex.com/

Comment: It is still a bit buggy.  Look for updates with more features and fixes soon.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your definition of easy, but you could write a SQL Update linking the backlog item(s) to the correct backlog items.

(If there is no field in the backlog item to connect it to another backlog item, you would have to extend backlog item and the views showing them yourself)